# Flutter error: The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building KeyedSubtree. Error: Could not find the correct Provider<AuthCubit> above

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, provider, cubit

I'm using Flutter BloC to write my LogIn&SignUp&Confirmation page.

I got the error when I go to "**SignUp page**" (when I click that button).

**Error:**

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building
KeyedSubtree-[GlobalKey#76df5]:
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<AuthCubit> above this
_InheritedProviderScope<SignUpBloc?> Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the
provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.

- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.

- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying
to read.

  Make sure that _InheritedProviderScope<SignUpBloc?> is under your
MultiProvider/Provider<AuthCubit>.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it
  immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>().toString()),
    );
  }
  

  consider using `builder` like so:

  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the
      provider
      builder: (context, child) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>().toString());
      }
    );
  }
  

If none of these solutions work, consider asking for help on StackOverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  Scaffold
  Scaffold:file:///Users/kelly_hung/study_savvy_app/lib/screens/sign_up.dart:15:
  12

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Provider._inheritedElementOf (package:provider/src/provider.dart:343:7)
#1      Provider.of (package:provider/src/provider.dart:293:30)
#2      ReadContext.read (package:provider/src/provider.dart:649:21)
#3      main.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
(package:study_savvy_app/main.dart:81:112)
#4      _CreateInheritedProviderState.value
(package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:736:36)
#5      _InheritedProviderScopeElement.value
(package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:590:33)
#6      Provider.of (package:provider/src/provider.dart:303:37)
#7      ReadContext.read (package:provider/src/provider.dart:649:21)
#8      _BlocListenerBaseState.initState
(package:flutter_bloc/src/bloc_listener.dart:143:36)
#9      StatefulElement._firstBuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5219:55)
#10     ComponentElement.mount
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5062:5)
#11     SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:222:11)
#12     Element.inflateWidget
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3971:16)
#13     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6570:36)
#14     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6582:32)
...     Normal element mounting (25 frames)
#39     Element.inflateWidget
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3971:16)
#40     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6570:36)
#41     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6582:32)
...     Normal element mounting (134 frames)
#175    Element.inflateWidget
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3971:16)
#176    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6570:36)
#177    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6582:32)
...     Normal element mounting (178 frames)
#355    Element.inflateWidget
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3971:16)
#356    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6570:36)
#357    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3708:18)
#358    RenderObjectElement.updateChildren
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6153:32)
#359    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6595:17)
#360    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#361    ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#362    StatefulElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#363    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#364    StatefulElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5274:5)
#365    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#366    ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#367    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#368    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5417:5)
#369    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#370    ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#371    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#372    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5417:5)
#373    _InheritedNotifierElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart:107:11)
#374    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#375    ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#376    StatefulElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#377    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#378    StatefulElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5274:5)
#379    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#380    ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#381    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#382    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5417:5)
#383    _InheritedNotifierElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart:107:11)
#384    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#385    ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#386    StatefulElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#387    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#388    StatefulElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5274:5)
#389    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#390    ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#391    StatefulElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#392    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#393    StatefulElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5274:5)
#394    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#395    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6442:14)
#396    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#397    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6442:14)
#398    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#399    ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#400    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#401    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5417:5)
#402    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3686:15)
#403    ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#404    StatefulElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#405    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#406    BuildOwner.buildScope
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2780:19)
#407    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame
(package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:903:21)
#408    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback
(package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:358:5)
#409    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback
(package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1284:15)
#410    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame
(package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1214:9)
#411    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame
(package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1072:5)
#412    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:142:13)
#413    PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:359:5)
#414    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:112:31)

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
════════════════════

Another exception was thrown: Each child must be laid out exactly once.
Another exception was thrown: Updated layout information required for
RenderErrorBox#5cb32 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT to calculate semantics.
```

**My code:**

main.dart:

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(DevicePreview(
      enabled: !kReleaseMode,
      builder: (context) => MultiProvider(
            providers: [
              RepositoryProvider(
                create: (context) => AuthRepository(),
              ),
              ChangeNotifierProvider(
                create: (_) => ThemeProvider(),
              ),
              ChangeNotifierProvider(
                create: (_) => OCRImageProvider(),
              ),
              BlocProvider(
                create: (context) => PageBloc(),
              ),
              BlocProvider(
                create: (context) => JWTBloc(),
              ),
              BlocProvider(
                create: (context) => FileBloc(),
              ),
              BlocProvider(
                create: (context) => FilesBloc(),
              ),
              BlocProvider(
                create: (context) => ProfileBloc(),
              ),
              BlocProvider(
                create: (context) => AccessMethodBloc(),
              ),
              BlocProvider(
                create: (context) => ArticleBloc(),
              ),
              BlocProvider(
                create: (context) => PasswordBloc(),
              ),
                BlocProvider(
                  create: (context) => LoginBloc(authRepo: context.read<AuthRepository>(), authCubit: AuthCubit(sessionCubit: SessionCubit(authRepo: AuthRepository())))
                ),
                BlocProvider(
                  create: (context) => SignUpBloc(authRepo: context.read<AuthRepository>(), authCubit: context.read<AuthCubit>())
                ),
              BlocProvider(
                create:  (context) => PasswordBloc(),
              ),
              BlocProvider(
                create:  (context) => OnlineBloc(),
              ),
              BlocProvider(
                create:  (context) 
                            => SessionCubit(authRepo: context.read<AuthRepository>(),),
                child: AppNavigator(), //responsible for showing the view
              ),
            ],
            child: const MyApp(),
          )));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);
    return 
    // RepositoryProvider(
    //   create: (context) => AuthRepository(),
    //   child: 
      MaterialApp(
        locale: DevicePreview.locale(context),
        builder: DevicePreview.appBuilder,
        title: 'Study-Savvy',
        theme: LightStyle.theme,
        darkTheme: DarkStyle.theme,
        themeMode: themeProvider.themeMode,
         //initialRoute: Routes.home,
        onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/initial.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          )),
          child: const HomePage(),

        )
      //)
      );
  }
}
```

sign_up.dart:

```dart
class SignUpView extends StatelessWidget {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // body: BlocProvider(
      //   create: (context) => SignUpBloc(
      //     authRepo: context.read<AuthRepository>(),
      //     authCubit: context.read<AuthCubit>(),
      //   ),
        //child: 
        body:
        Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          children: [
            _signUpForm(),
            _showLoginButton(context),
          ],
        ),
      //),
    );
  }

  Widget _signUpForm() {
    return BlocListener<SignUpBloc, SignUpState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          final formStatus = state.formStatus;
          if (formStatus is SubmissionFailed) {
            _showSnackBar(context, formStatus.exception.toString());
          }
        },
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                _usernameField(),
                _emailField(),
                _passwordField(),
                _signUpButton(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  Widget _usernameField() {
    return BlocBuilder<SignUpBloc, SignUpState>(builder: (context, state) {
      return TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          icon: Icon(Icons.person),
          hintText: 'Username',
        ),
        validator: (value) =>
            state.isValidUsername ? null : 'Username is too short',
        onChanged: (value) => context.read<SignUpBloc>().add(
              SignUpUsernameChanged(username: value),
            ),
      );
    });
  }

  Widget _emailField() {
    return BlocBuilder<SignUpBloc, SignUpState>(builder: (context, state) {
      return TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          icon: Icon(Icons.person),
          hintText: 'Email',
        ),
        validator: (value) => state.isValidUsername ? null : 'Invalid email',
        onChanged: (value) => context.read<SignUpBloc>().add(
              SignUpEmailChanged(email: value),
            ),
      );
    });
  }

  Widget _passwordField() {
    return BlocBuilder<SignUpBloc, SignUpState>(builder: (context, state) {
      return TextFormField(
        obscureText: true,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          icon: Icon(Icons.security),
          hintText: 'Password',
        ),
        validator: (value) =>
            state.isValidPassword ? null : 'Password is too short',
        onChanged: (value) => context.read<SignUpBloc>().add(
              SignUpPasswordChanged(password: value),
            ),
      );
    });
  }

  Widget _signUpButton() {
    return BlocBuilder<SignUpBloc, SignUpState>(builder: (context, state) {
      return state.formStatus is FormSubmitting
          ? CircularProgressIndicator()
          : ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                  context.read<SignUpBloc>().add(SignUpSubmitted());
                }
              },
              child: Text('Sign Up'),
            );
    });
  }

  Widget _showLoginButton(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: TextButton(
        child: Text('Already have an account? Sign in.'),
        onPressed: () => context.read<AuthCubit>().showLogin(),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showSnackBar(BuildContext context, String message) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(message));
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }
}
```

SignUp_bloc.dart:

```dart
class SignUpBloc extends Bloc<SignUpEvent, SignUpState> {
  final AuthRepository authRepo;
  final AuthCubit authCubit;

  SignUpBloc({required this.authRepo, required this.authCubit})
     : super(SignUpState()){
      on<SignUpEvent>(_onEvent);
     }

  Future<void> _onEvent(SignUpEvent event, Emitter<SignUpState> emit) async {
    // Username updated
    if (event is SignUpUsernameChanged) {
      emit(state.copyWith(username: event.username));

      // Email updated
    } else if (event is SignUpEmailChanged) {
      emit(state.copyWith(email: event.email));

      // Password updated
    } else if (event is SignUpPasswordChanged) {
      emit(state.copyWith(password: event.password));

      // Form submitted
    } else if (event is SignUpSubmitted) {
      emit(state.copyWith(formStatus: FormSubmitting()));

      try {
        await authRepo.signUp(
          username: state.username,
          email: state.email,
          password: state.password,
        );
        emit(state.copyWith(formStatus: SubmissionSuccess()));

        authCubit.showConfirmSignUp( 
          username: state.username,
          email: state.email,
          password: state.password,
        );
      } catch (e) {
        emit(state.copyWith(formStatus: SubmissionFailed(e.toString() as Exception)));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

auth_cubit:

```dart
enum AuthState { login, signUp, confirmSignUp }

class AuthCubit extends Cubit<AuthState> {
  final SessionCubit sessionCubit;

  AuthCubit({required this.sessionCubit}) : super(AuthState.login);

  late AuthCredentials credentials;

  void showLogin() => emit(AuthState.login);
  void showSignUp() => emit(AuthState.signUp);
  void showConfirmSignUp({
    required String username,
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) {
    credentials = AuthCredentials(  //crate right here, to hand on argument
      username: username,
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );
    emit(AuthState.confirmSignUp); //show confirm view
  }

  void launchSession(AuthCredentials credentials) =>
      sessionCubit.showSession(credentials);
}
```

auth_navigator.dart:

```dart
class AuthNavigator extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<AuthCubit, AuthState>(builder: (context, state) {
      return Navigator(
        pages: [
          // Show login
          if (state == AuthState.login) MaterialPage(child: SignInPage()),

          // Allow push animation
          if (state == AuthState.signUp ||
              state == AuthState.confirmSignUp) ...[
            // Show Sign up
            MaterialPage(child: SignUpView()),

            // Show confirm sign up
            if (state == AuthState.confirmSignUp)
              MaterialPage(child: ConfirmationView())
          ]
        ],
        onPopPage: (route, result) => route.didPop(result),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

session_cubit.dart:

```dart
class SessionCubit extends Cubit<SessionState> {
  final AuthRepository authRepo;

  SessionCubit({required this.authRepo}) : super(UnknownSessionState()) {
    attemptAutoLogin();
  }

  void attemptAutoLogin() async {
    try {
      final userId = await authRepo.attemptAutoLogin();
      // final user = dataRepo.getUser(userId);
      final user = userId;
      emit(Authenticated(user: user));
    } on Exception {
      emit(Unauthenticated());
    }
  }

  void showAuth() => emit(Unauthenticated());
  void showSession(AuthCredentials credentials) {
    // final user = dataRepo.getUser(credentials.userId);
    final user = credentials.username;
    emit(Authenticated(user: user));
  }

  void signOut() {
    authRepo.signOut();
    emit(Unauthenticated());
  }
}
```

app_navigator.dart:

```
class AppNavigator extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<SessionCubit, SessionState>(builder: (context, state) {
      return Navigator(
        pages: [
          // Show loading screen
          if (state is UnknownSessionState) MaterialPage(child: LoadingView()),

          // Show auth flow
          if (state is Unauthenticated)
            MaterialPage(
              child: BlocProvider(
                create: (context) =>
                    AuthCubit(sessionCubit: context.read<SessionCubit>()),
                child: AuthNavigator(),  
              ),
            ),

          // Show session flow
          if (state is Authenticated) MaterialPage(child: HomePage())
        ],
        onPopPage: (route, result) => route.didPop(result),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

I followed the tutorial on YouTube step by step ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iX-SOXrXO9U)), and changing some details. For example, I have Initial.dart to navigate to sign in/up page in the beginning.

The app can run properly when I choose SignIn button, and go to my following pages.

However, when I click "Sign Up" button , no matter in which page, the screen is empty and occur error.

Thank you so much!!! :))

Comment: Please only poste the relevant part of your code and remove the other parts. It's hard to read.

Comment: Sorry about that! (I'm not sure which parts of code cause errors). I edited this post and remove some of them, please help me!!

Comment: Please provide import paths. My IDE shows so many items in red underline. So many unknown variables, what additional packages are required in pubspec.yaml to reproduce your issue?. Better if you also paste your code at something like https://dartpad.dev and share the link here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

from `auth Navigator` page when you are moving to `sign up` page

you have to provide `auth cubit` to `sign up` page.

here

```
MaterialPage(child: SignUpView()),
```

use `BlocProvider.value` and provide the value of auth cubit to the `signup` page

replace with this,

```
MaterialPage(child: BlocProvider.value(
                    value:context.read<AuthCubit>(), child: SignUpView()),
```

Then it will work.

Comment: Thank for your reply! But I changed my "auth Navigator" page, the error still exist;(